# how to get file from IOS and then send it through PHP api in email as attachment

Tags: php, ios

i am working on an API for IOS app where user would have a small form that have three fields 1. file type where he could just type text e.g image or pdf only 2. in second field he could just browse pdf or image of any type like png,jpg etc in his cell and 3.Remarks: where he could give some remarks.

After he fill all the fields he would click send and the admin will get the email with the image attachment.

now i am facing an issue when i hard code the file name in array and keep that file on the server as well like

```
  $files = array("myimage.png");
```

it works fine attach them file with email and send it but i want to make it automatic like user enter related data and my api do it automatically.

here is the code i have worked so far

```
 <?php

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "FILE NAME: ".$_FILES['file']['filename'];

// array with filenames to be sent as attachment
 //$files = array("1378326315_joomla.png");
   $files = $_FILES['file']['filename']; 
 //email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
   $to = "admin email";
   $from = "user name here"; 
   $subject ="this "; 
   $message = "My message";
   $headers = "From: $from";

// boundary 
   $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
   $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

  // headers for attachment 
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . "        boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

  // multipart boundary 
     $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--   {$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-    Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
     $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
$file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
$data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    } 

    // send

       $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
       if ($ok) { 
   echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
       } else { 
   echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
       } 


  } else {
  echo "Nothing";
}


?>
```

i can easily handle this whole functionality in php for web but i am confused for IOS as its my First ever API and interaction with i phone. hope my question is clear and i will surely give more details if require and i missed it. thanks in advance for help.

EDIT:one thing more i want to add there is no need of saveing any data in db acording to the requirements but should i save file in any folder on server first before send??

Comment: i think this time i asked a very complex question that no one can answer. where are you my PHP tigers????

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSURLRequest *)createRequestWithPath:(NSString *)path withKeys:(NSDictionary *)postKeys withData:(NSData *)data
```

{
    //create the URL POST Request to tumblr

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.28/index.php?/%@",path];

NSURL *tumblrURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSMutableURLRequest *tumblrPost = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tumblrURL];
[tumblrPost setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Add the header info
//NSString *stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY"];
NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",stringBoundary];
[tumblrPost addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//create the body
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//add key values from the NSDictionary object

if (![postKeys isEqual:nil]) 
{
    NSEnumerator *keys = [postKeys keyEnumerator];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [postKeys count]; i++) {
        NSString *tempKey = [keys nextObject];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",tempKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[postKeys objectForKey:tempKey]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
}

if (![data isEqual:nil])
{
    NSLog(@"data size : %i",[data length]);
    //add data field and file data
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

self.dataSize = [postBody length];
//add the body to the post
[tumblrPost setHTTPBody:postBody];
return tumblrPost;
```

}

also look up [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: whats this bro u sent me ios script but i posted php API script and need solution over there. ok one thing more i know this whole functionality is possible through iphone APP instead but there is a problem i am unable to remove cc and bcc from there i only need one field for email no cc and bcc so how to remaove it

Comment: you can use that code for catch user's sent image data on server

Comment: lolx its a very complex solution as i am unable to understand this code completly more confused now

Comment: but i explained every thing what else need to explaing this the whole thing i need